# How to use the wait() method in java

Tags: java, multithreading

Why the t1 thread can't be notify after 3 seconds?

```
    public class MyThread extends Thread{
        public MyThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    //private int ticket = 100;
    public void run() {
        synchronized(this) {
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " run ");

            while(true)
                ;

        }
    }
}


    public class MultieThreadTest {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyThread t1 = new MyThread("t1");

        synchronized(t1) {
            try {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " start t1 ");
                t1.start();

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " call wait 3000ms");
                t1.wait(3000);

                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " continue ");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The result is：

main start t1

main call wait 3000ms

t1 run

But I think it should be:

main start t1

main call wait 3000ms

t1 run

//after 3 seconds

main continue

Comment: You have two threads running, but both are synchronized on the same monitor...

Comment: Your expectations are incorrect. And you call `wait()` but not `notify()`. You need to read the Javadoc.

Comment: `synchronized` should be used on the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `t1.wait(3000);` with `Thread.sleep(3000);` for the delay.

`Object.wait()` is used to suspend the method until some other thread calls `Object.notify()` or `Object.notifyAll()` on same object to resume the suspended thread.

Refer the link:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-notify